# If someone had to die

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence below in second conditional and indicate future?

▪ "**If someone had to die, I thought it should be me**," he later told his parents.

Comment: More than likely, in this example, both clauses were happening at the same time.

Comment: This is reported speech, backshifted from _If someone has to die, I think it should be me_.

Comment: "I thought that, if someone had to die, it should be me" is the more logical ordering.

Comment: It's reporting an event (his thinking) that happened in the past.

Comment: To me it ought to be either, “If someone had to die, I thought it should have been me.”  OR “If someone had to die, I thought, ’It should be me. ’”

Comment: Thanks to all 